# What are the package dependencies for httpd? (rhel 5)

Tags: redhat, httpd

Our company uses home brewed repositories and a system to configure them, which is conveniently not working at the moment. This is causing a problem for me since I can't add repositories, and therefore can't install software on this RHEL 5 box.

I can log in to red hat and download packages, but I can't find a listing of everything included in the package group when you run "yum install httpd." Can anyone provide a list of those packages? I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doesn't RPM just flat out tell you what you're missing when you try to install the package?  eg: `rpm -ivh httpd-whatever.rpm`

How about this for the actual packages:
`# for LINE in $(rpm -qR httpd);do rpm -q --whatprovides $LINE; done | sort | uniq | grep -v "no package provides"`

```
apr-1.2.7-11.el5_6.5
apr-util-1.2.7-11.el5_5.2
bash-3.2-32.el5
chkconfig-1.3.30.2-2.el5
coreutils-5.97-34.0.1.el5_8.1
db4-4.3.29-10.el5_5.2
expat-1.95.8-11.el5_8
file-4.17-28
findutils-4.2.27-6.el5
gawk-3.1.5-16.el5
glibc-2.5-107
httpd-2.2.3-76.0.1.el5_9
initscripts-8.45.42-1.0.3.el5_8.1
libselinux-1.33.4-5.7.el5
mailcap-2.1.23-1.fc6
mktemp-1.5-24.el5
openldap-2.3.43-25.el5_8.1
openssl-0.9.8e-26.el5_9.1
pcre-6.6-6.el5_6.1
shadow-utils-4.0.17-21.el5
zlib-1.2.3-7.el5
```

This is for `httpd-2.2.3-76.0.1.el5_9`

Comment: The problem I am running into is the output lists a number of shared objects, which don't have clear packages that provide them. When I do find them, they in turn have more dependencies. There's an old term, "dependency hell." That's where I am right now. So I am trying to find a list of all packages in the httpd group.

Comment: OK, see my edit.  That should be more useful.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** The following answer is wrong, but kept for posterity. Learn from my shame and failure.

Give the following command a go: `yum deplist httpd` (This requires a repository to be accessible to determine dependencies, so is useless in this scenario where repos are not available.)

Comment: Sadly that requires a repo to be accessible, which none are currently because our config script is having problems.

Comment: @Matthew You are correct - I missed that. Christoper's will be the correct answer then. =)

Answer (score 0):

You may find it easier to use **pkgs.org** for dependency resolution.

It's especially handy when you don't have access to the system or the system is somehow broken.

Here's the dependencies for httpd in RHEL5:

http://pkgs.org/centos-5-rhel-5/centos-rhel-x86_64/httpd-2.2.3-74.el5.centos.x86_64.rpm.html